# Shifting daily data exactly one month forward (not 30 days)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-dateutil

I want to shift the date index of my daily data forward by one month. This is in order to calculate a rolling month-on-month change on the daily data by calculating on two dataframes - the existing one with the correct time stamps and a new one with the time stamps shifted forward one month with all the other data columns the same

The problem is that not all months have the same length, so I don't want to roll it forward by 30 days. I would like for example the 24th of March to match with 24th of February (28 days), and the 24th of April to match the 24th March (31 days).

I tried variations of the following with no joy:

```
df= pd.read_csv("seven_day.csv", parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])

df.shift(periods=1, freq="M")
df.shift(periods=1, freq="MS")
```

What happens is I get the end or start of the next month for ALL of the days in the current month. Eg all March daily data days go to the end or start of April.

Would massively appreciate any insight.

Comment: What to do for 31th of January?

Comment: 31st of Jan matches with 31st Dec, and 28th Feb matches with 31st Jan

Comment: Do you mind too share a [mcve]? Here you are not sharing any data.

Comment: It's ambiguous to try to match the 28th of February to the 31st of January (but you can unambiguously match the 31st of January to the 28th of February if you shift up). Unless explicitly using month ends (which is not the case here as you discussed the 24th of March), you can only unambiguously round **down** a month (e.g., 31->30, 30->28). If you start from 28, there is no way to unambiguously know if you should match the 28th before or the 31st.

Comment: Thanks Mozway - I think this works. So I should be shifting forward a month (+1) rather than back? The format of my dates seem to change in the column which may be a separate issue - just checking

Comment: It depends what you want exactly. Can you give an explicit minimal example of your 2 input DataFrames and the explicit expected output?

Comment: Then share the one DataFrame, and the expected output (try to make the example meaningful) ;)

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the above - actually makes sense to shift back a month. So in the case of March to Feb, I'd want 31st, 30th, 29th and 28th all to refer to 28th Feb.

Comment: Which is what the offset would do, everything ≥ 28 March would become 28th of February (on non leap years)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
df.set_index(df.index+pd.DateOffset(months=1))
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': range(6)},
                   index=pd.to_datetime(['2022-12-31', '2023-01-24',
                                         '2023-01-31', '2023-02-24',
                                         '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31']))

df.join(df.set_index(df.index+pd.DateOffset(months=1)).add_suffix('_shift'))
```

Output:

```
            data  data_shift
2022-12-31     0         NaN
2023-01-24     1         NaN
2023-01-31     2         0.0 # matches 2021-12-31
2023-02-24     3         1.0 # matches 2023-01-24
2023-02-28     4         2.0 # matches 2023-01-31
2023-03-31     5         NaN
```

Intermediate:

```
df.set_index(df.index+pd.DateOffset(months=1)).add_suffix('_shift')

            data_shift
2023-01-31           0
2023-02-24           1
2023-02-28           2
2023-03-24           3
2023-03-28           4
2023-04-30           5
```

##### Other way around (note the `-` sign):

```
df.join(df.set_index(df.index-pd.DateOffset(months=1)).add_suffix('_shift'))
# or
df.join(df.set_index(df.index+pd.DateOffset(months=-1)).add_suffix('_shift'))
```

Output:

```
            data  data_shift
2022-12-31     0         2.0 # matches 2021-01-31
2023-01-24     1         3.0 # matches 2021-02-24
2023-01-31     2         NaN
2023-02-24     3         NaN
2023-02-28     4         5.0 # matches 2023-03-31
2023-03-31     5         NaN
```

Intermediate:

```
df.set_index(df.index-pd.DateOffset(months=1)).add_suffix('_shift')

            data_shift
2022-11-30           0
2022-12-24           1
2022-12-31           2
2023-01-24           3
2023-01-28           4
2023-02-28           5
```